# How do I request for an increase in quota storage limit in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

How do I request for an increase in quota storage limit in BigQuery

I get this error when I try to run my table load query. There's no billing account added to the BQ account. However, data size doesn't seem to be exceeding 1TB limit.
Any help is appreciated!!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMGx0.png)

Comment: You may have run out of free data processing -- bigquery charges based on data processed cumulatively (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing)